# Java Listener not working unless i press enter how to enable it working once text box changed

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield, documentlistener

I have sticked below listener inside JtextField when action performed event,
so as to perform action against any change made in text box once user make any change.
but the problem is the code not starting or working unless you press enter only then
the code execute the code, i need  to know what i have to add and where to enable  below code once text Filed changed instantly .I can see some similar help referring  to Oracle listener help but am unable to manage so i need direct simple way.

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
jTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Change case");
} 
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update Case");
}

public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Remove case");
 }
});
 // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActionListener` for a text field only listens for <kbd>enter</kbd> key being typed. So what your code essentialy does is: when <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed adds a new `DocumentListener` to the text field.

The `DocumentListener` is what you want so take that code (adding the document listener) out of the `jTextField1ActionPerformed` method and put it in the constructor of the class. Or have a private method, so as not to clutter the constructor.

Assuming you are using Netbeans GUI editor (looks like it from your method signature):

```
public class MyFrame exentds JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();
        addDocumentListenerToField();
    }

    private void addDocumentListenerToField() {
        jTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(..);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE: DEMO**

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class DocListeenerDemo extends JFrame {
    private JTextField field;   
    private JLabel label;

    public DocListeenerDemo() {
        initComponents();
        addDocumentListenerToField();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        field = new JTextField(20);
        label = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(field);
        add(label);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    private void addDocumentListenerToField() {
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {doYourStuff();}
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {doYourStuff();}
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {doYourStuff();}
            public void doYourStuff() {
                label.setText(field.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                DocListeenerDemo demo = new DocListeenerDemo();
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have not figure out a way to add the `DocumentListener` through the GUI tool. Sucks.

Comment: still not clear i have add the same code into jframe class in the startup and i have made method but still showing error please can you help am still in middle of the road

Comment: See my **UPDATE**. It's a demo, hopefully you can work off of.

Comment: Perfect last good news this is what am looking to have since last days.

Answer (score 0):

try using `actionListener` rather than `documentListener`

Comment: what you mean can you give full answer am still unable to get clear working code